# Division by table column

Tags: c#

Can i know why the divider is not showing value?

```
    select gg.columnA ,t.columnB, (gg.columnA / t.columnB) as C
    FROM #main t
LEFT OUTER JOIN #Total_ByGradeGender gg
    ON t.OrganizationCd = gg.OrganizationCd
    AND t.CountryCd = gg.CountryCd
    where t.organizationcd = '27849'
```

The value for last column is always showing 0. Isn't should be columnA/12 ?

```
8   12  0
1   12  0
3   12  0
```

If i change the divider to an integer, then the value will show.

Comment: Is the column type `int`? What would you like `1 / 12` to display?

Comment: `8 / 12 = 0.66` then obviously it will be zero

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast to numeric

```
select gg.columnA ,t.columnB, (gg.columnA /cast( t.columnB as numeric))  as C
   FROM #main t
LEFT OUTER JOIN #Total_ByGradeGender gg
ON t.OrganizationCd = gg.OrganizationCd
AND t.CountryCd = gg.CountryCd
where t.organizationcd = '27849'
```